# (matplotlib) Как увеличить интервалы?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Как увеличить интервал между надписями?
Код:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['Category'].value_counts()).plot(kind='barh', figsize=(10,15))
plt.show()
```

Фрейм:
[image]

Comment: Увеличьте размер фигуры (figsize). Либо выводите не все метки. либо уменьшите размер шрифта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я уже советовал, либо измените размер фигуры:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['Category'].value_counts()).plot(kind='barh', figsize=(10,25))
```

либо выводите не все метки, но это вам вряд ли подойдет,
либо уменьшайте шрифт меток:

стандарт:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если изменить размер шрифта:

```
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

либо используйте вызов

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]